# Practical difference between a struct with only operator() and a normal function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have seen code that looks like this:

```cpp
struct foo_functor {
  template <typename T, typename U>
  constexpr auto operator()(T t, U u) const -> decltype(t | u) {
    return t | u;
  }
};

constexpr foo_functor foo;
```

As far as I can tell, it's the same as the following:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto foo(T t, U u) -> decltype(t | u) {
  return t | u;
}
```

Why would you want to do the first one? Are there any differences? As far as I could see from the compiler output, at least with `constexpr`, there wasn't. What about if they weren't `constexpr`, would there be any differences in that case?

Edit: As a note, code very similar to the first example was seemingly being used in place of normal functions. 6 different structures, all with only `operator()` templates, all were instantiated like the last line of the example. Each was then used exactly like a normal function.

Comment: The `foo_functor` can have additional state (very useful!), and also other associated behaviors (not as useful).  A lambda is syntactic sugar for a functor, and a lambda with `auto` parameters is syntactic sugar for a template functor.

Answer (score 7):

Someone suggested in the comments that a function object can have additional state. While this is true, I would be a bit more specific: you can create multiple copies of a function object with varying state. If the function object is singleton, then this point is moot; a function can also have state in the form of global variables.

And if your function object is declared `constexpr`, then none of its internal state can be mutable. This puts it in the same position as a `constexpr` function: calling it can be a constant expression but only as long as it doesn't access any non-constant-expression *global* state.

One important difference before C++17 is that functions could be `inline`, whereas objects could not be. In C++14, if you defined the functor `foo` in a header, then there would be one copy of it per translation unit. If you needed `foo` to have the same address in all translation units, you would need to declare it as an `inline` function. But in C++17, function objects can be inline too.

But even if you only have a single instance of the function object, and it has no state, and you are using C++17 or later, there is still at least one important difference between that and a function: functions can be found by argument-dependent lookup, whereas function objects cannot. This is the reason why some "functions" in the C++20 Ranges library actually cannot be functions at all, and must be function objects. These are informally referred to as [niebloids](https://thephd.github.io/a-weakness-in-the-niebloids).

Comment: Another case: When passed as a parameter to a function, a function becomes `ReturnType (*ptr)(ParamType)` and gets passed by pointer, and the compiler may have trouble inlining it.  The Functoid passes as `foo_functor`, so the compiler knows _exactly_ what function will be called, and has no problem inlining it. This can result in increased performance.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I would add that you cannot pass function templates around, whereas you can pass function objects with templated call operator around.