# What is a niebloid?

Tags: c++, c++20

With C++20 we can read the term "niebloid" more often now in the cppreference.

On SO we can find today 2020/07/16  2 articles mentioning it:

- [First post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62093977/practical-difference-between-a-struct-with-only-operator-and-a-normal-function/62094376#62094376)
- [Second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495848/what-are-customization-point-objects-and-how-to-use-them/53516153#53516153), talking about customization point objects

Google does also not spit out that many results. The most prominent is maybe [here](https://thephd.github.io/a-weakness-in-the-niebloids).

Can somebody shed a little bit more light on niebloids?

Comment: A definition can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of in which `std::range::all_of` is an example for a `niebloid`.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The term **niebloid** comes from **Eric Niebler's** name. In simple words, they are function objects that disable ADL (argument-dependent lookup) from happening so that the overloads in `std::` aren't picked up when an algorithm from `std::ranges` is called.

Here's a tweet (from 2018) and answer from [**Eric** himself](https://twitter.com/tcanens/status/1063723279414890496?s=20) suggesting the name. Eric wrote an [article](http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/) in 2014 explaining this concept.

It can best be seen in action in the [standard document itself](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#2):

> **25.2.2**
> The entities defined in the `std​::​ranges` namespace in this Clause are not found by argument-dependent name lookup ([basic.lookup.argdep](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep)).
> When found by unqualified ([basic.lookup.unqual](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual)) name lookup for the postfix-expression in a function call, they inhibit argument-dependent name lookup.
>
> ```
> void foo() {
>   using namespace std::ranges;
>   std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
>   find(begin(vec), end(vec), 2);        // #1
> }
> ```
>
> The function call expression at `#1` invokes `std​::​ranges​::​find`, not `std​::​find`, despite that (a) the iterator type returned from `begin(vec)` and `end(vec)` may be associated with `namespace std` and (b) `std​::​find` is more specialized ([temp.func.order]) than `std​::​ranges​::​find` since the former requires its first two parameters to have the same type.

The above example has *ADL* turned off, so the call goes directly to `std::ranges::find`.

Let's create a small example to explore this further:

```
namespace mystd
{
    class B{};
    class A{};
    template<typename T>
    void swap(T &a, T &b)
    {
        std::cout << "mystd::swap\n";
    }
}

namespace sx
{
    namespace impl {
       //our functor, the niebloid
        struct __swap {
            template<typename R, typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<R, mystd::A>::value >  >
            void operator()(R &a, R &b) const
            {
                std::cout << "in sx::swap()\n";
                // swap(a, b); 
            }
        };
    }
    inline constexpr impl::__swap swap{};
}

int main()
{
    mystd::B a, b;
    swap(a, b); // calls mystd::swap()

    using namespace sx;
    mystd::A c, d;
    swap(c, d); //No ADL!, calls sx::swap!

    return 0;
}
```

Description from [cppreference](http://cpp.arh.pub.ro/Template:cpp/ranges/niebloid):

> The function-like entities described on this page are niebloids, that is:
>
> - Explicit template argument lists may not be specified when calling any of them.
> - None of them is visible to argument-dependent lookup.
> - When one of them is found by normal unqualified lookup for the name to the left of the function-call operator, it inhibits argument-dependent lookup.

Niebloids aren't visible to argument dependent lookup(ADL) because they are function objects, and ADL is done only for free functions and not function objects. The third point is what happened in the example from the standard:

```
find(begin(vec), end(vec), 2); //unqualified call to find
```

The call to `find()` is unqualified, so when lookup starts, it finds `std::ranges::find` function object which in turn stops ADL from happening.

Searching some more, I found [this](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/08/02/the-tough-guide-to-cpp-acronyms/#cpo) which, in my opinion is the most understandable explanation of niebloids and CPOs (customization point objects):

> ... a **CPO** is an object (not a function); it’s callable; it’s constexpr-constructible, [...] it’s customizable (that’s what it means to “interact with program-defined types”); and it’s concept-constrained.
> [...]
> *If you remove the adjectives “customizable, concept-constrained” from the above, then you have a function object that turns off ADL — but is not necessarily a customization point*. The C++2a Ranges algorithms, such as `std::ranges::find`, are like this. *Any callable, constexpr-constructible object is colloquially known as a “niebloid,”* in honor of Eric Niebler.

Comment: Niebloids are _not_ guaranteed to be objects. They are specified as magical function templates with enough weasel wording to allow them to be implemented as objects, but no more.

Comment: When I read posts like this I realize just how much I do not know.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. Is `(f)(x)` not stopping ADL from happening?

Comment: What mechanism does `std::ranges::find` use in order to stop ADL, when found?

Comment: "ADL-immune function" from that poll seems like a much better, self-descriptive name. Why isn't that used instead?

Comment: I suggested "niebloid" with tongue firmly in cheek. To my chagrin, it stuck. Serves me right.

Comment: As the 'oid' suffix represents similarity, does it mean that Eric is inflexible, self-centered, and an obstacle aginst further research? Just kidding 

Comment: @EricNiebler: So more appropriately, niebloids de-activate Koenig lookup ? 

Answer (score 4):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of):

The function-like entities described on this page are **niebloids**, that is:

- Explicit template argument lists may not be specified when calling any of them.
- None of them is visible to argument-dependent lookup.
- When one of them is found by normal unqualified lookup for the name to the left of the function-call operator, it inhibits argument-dependent lookup.

In practice, they may be implemented as function objects, or with special compiler extensions.