# Can ranges::equal be used as a predicate for a pair of transform_view ranges?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, std-ranges

##### Example Program and Compiler Errors

The following code produces two compiler errors (MSVC++ 2022 compiling with `/std:c++latest` because `<ranges>` isn't yet enabled for `/std:c++20` at time of writing this question):

```
error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
error C7602: 'std::ranges::_Equal_fn::operator ()': the associated constraints are not satisfied
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    using std::views::transform;
    std::vector<std::string> foo{ "THe", "CaT", "SaT", "oN", "THe", "MaT" };
    std::vector<std::string> bar{ "The", "Cat", "Sat", "On", "The", "Mat" };

    bool are_equal = std::ranges::equal(
        foo | transform(transform(std::tolower)),
        bar | transform(transform(std::tolower)),
        std::ranges::equal
    );

    std::cout 
        << "vectors 'foo' and 'bar' are equal? - "
        << std::boolalpha << are_equal << std::endl;
}
```

##### Analysis

My guess regarding the first error `__surrogate_func` appears to be attempting to use `operator==` between the two `transform_view::iterator`s
([As far as I can tell, the iterator defines `operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view/iterator)).

The second error appears to relate to a constraint for `std::ranges::equal::operator()`.

As far as I can tell, a constraint does not seem to be satisfied by `transform_view`, or perhaps more specifically, `transform_view::iterator`.

Looking at the source for `..\include\algorithm`, `ranges::equal` is an instance of `class _Equal_fn`, with `_Equal_fn::operator()` having constraint
`requires indirectly_comparable<iterator_t<_Rng1>, iterator_t<_Rng2>`.

I'm struggling to find anything on [cppreference/ranges/transform_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) to suggest that the `transform_view::iterator` is required to conform to this constraint, so I assume it's not supposed to.

However the implementation `_Equal_fn` clearly behaves as-expected when bypassed using a lambda without any constraints to wrap `ranges::equal`.  This alternative implementation compiles in MSVC++ and produces the expected result:

```cpp
    auto lambda_equal = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return std::ranges::equal(lhs, rhs);
    };

    // Now it compiles (MSVC++)
    bool are_equal = std::ranges::equal(
        foo | transform(transform(std::tolower)),
        bar | transform(transform(std::tolower)),
        lambda_equal
    );
```

(Which could be made a little more generic using a python-esque decorator pattern to make it generic enough for any other binary functionoid):

```cpp
constexpr auto binary_invocable = [](const auto& fn) {
    return [&fn](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return fn(lhs, rhs);
    };
};
```

```cpp
    // Now it compiles (MSVC++)
    bool are_equal = std::ranges::equal(
        foo | transform(transform(std::tolower)),
        bar | transform(transform(std::tolower)),
        binary_invocable(std::ranges::equal)
    );
```

##### Question:

On the basis that the problem appears to be with the constraint and not a lack of an `iterator::operator== ()`, is there any way, using standard library functions/functors to either wrap `range::equal` or to wrap `transform_view`, as a means to satisfying the `indirectly_comparable<iterator_t<Rng1>, iterator_t<Rng1>` constraint?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in [gcc-trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/E8MKbTqPT).

Comment: @康桓瑋 Thank you for checking - this leads me to suspect an issue specific to MSVC++.

Comment: It seems like your problem can be reduced to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/zPa9oTrsn).

Comment: That's a superb observation about the use of ranges::equal as a predicate, and rules out anything specific to transform_view, thank you a second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can `ranges::equal` be used as a predicate for a pair of transform_view ranges?

No, it cannot. This is because `ranges::equal` is colloquially referred to as a niebloid ([cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Template:cpp/ranges/niebloid), [blog](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/12/19/cpo-niebloid/)).

In the standard, they are defined in [[algorithms.requirements]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#requirements-2):

> The entities defined in the `std​::​ranges` namespace in this Clause are not found by argument-dependent name lookup ([basic.lookup.argdep]). When found by unqualified ([basic.lookup.unqual]) name lookup for the postfix-expression in a function call ([expr.call]), they inhibit argument-dependent name lookup.

That's it. Namely, `ranges::equal` is still presented as a function template - just as this special kind of function template that inhibits, and is not found by, argument-dependent lookup.

The only way to implement that in C++ today is as a function object. But they're not *specified* as function objects, so you cannot rely on function-object-like properties. Like copyability. libstdc++ simply implements them as empty function objects, but MSVC deliberately chooses to not provide any functionality not specified in the standard. Hence in MSVC's implementation, `ranges::equal` is not copyable -- because it is not specified to be an object, it's specified as a function template, and you cannot use function templates that way.

Answer (score 2):

The issue can be [reduced to](https://godbolt.org/z/4MY4xE5qj)

```
#include <algorithm>

static_assert(
  std::copy_constructible<decltype(std::ranges::equal)>);
```

Since [`ranges::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/equal) requires `Pred` must satisfy [`indirectly_comparable<I1, I2, Pred, Proj1, Proj2>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_comparable), which indirectly requires `Pred` must satisfy `copy_constructible`, so the constraints are not satisfied under MSVC. The standard doesn't require [*niebloid*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62928396/what-is-a-niebloid) to be copyable, so both gcc and MSVC are correct.

The reason why MSVC's function objects are not copyable is that they all inherit [`_Not_quite_object`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/2127ea00965ea536fe1d6adffb13e9e2466b1b8c/stl/inc/xutility#L2841), which is implemented as

```
class _Not_quite_object {
  _Not_quite_object(const _Not_quite_object&) = delete;
  _Not_quite_object& operator=(const _Not_quite_object&) = delete;
};
```

As stated in its [comments](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/2127ea00965ea536fe1d6adffb13e9e2466b1b8c/stl/inc/xutility#L2843)

> Some overload sets in the library have the property that their
> constituent function templates are not visible to argument-dependent
> name lookup (ADL) and that they inhibit ADL when found via unqualified
> name lookup.
> This property allows these overload sets to be
> implemented as function objects. **We derive such function objects from
> this type to remove some typical object-ish behaviors which helps
> users avoid depending on their non-specified object-ness.**

So you cannot pass `ranges::equal` as a function object, because the standard doesn't require it to be.

Comment: Aha - Barry's answer is a fine explanation as to *why* ranges::equal does not satisfy the constraint (and as you mention, it is not the right approach for this use-case),  however this also explains how `indirectly_comparable` constraint enforces the copy_constructible requirement for `Pred`,  which clearly MSVC has (quite rightly and reasonably) decided not to allow.    Great detective work!