# Why is this function call didn't reject the unsuitable overload?

Tags: c++, overloading, sfinae, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider the following code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<ranges>
#include<algorithm>
//using namespace std;
using namespace std::ranges;
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {};
    sort(a);
    return 0;
}
```

It's running properly.

Obviously, it called this overload function(functor, strictly speaking):

```
template<random_access_range _Range,
     typename _Comp = ranges::less, typename _Proj = identity>
  requires sortable<iterator_t<_Range>, _Comp, _Proj>
  constexpr borrowed_iterator_t<_Range>
  operator()(_Range&& __r, _Comp __comp = {}, _Proj __proj = {}) const
  {
return (*this)(ranges::begin(__r), ranges::end(__r),
           std::move(__comp), std::move(__proj));
  }
```

But after we introducing the namespace std, the function call became ambiguous(got compilation errors):

```
#include<vector>
#include<ranges>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::ranges;
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {};
    sort(a);
    return 0;
}
```

In addition to the previous reloads

```
 2045 |   inline constexpr __sort_fn sort{};
```

, there are many other overload functions found in namespace std like:

```
template<class _ExecutionPolicy, class _RandomAccessIterator> __pstl::__internal::__enable_if_execution_policy<_ExecutionPolicy, void> std::sort(_ExecutionPolicy&&, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator)
```

and

```
template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> constexpr void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)
```

So my questions are:

1. The call of sort functor in std::ranges is the best match function, isn't it? Why do these functions later found in std cause ambiguity, rather than being abandoned due to the SFINAE principle?
2. If the functions in std are visible for `sort(a)` after we introduced the namespace std, shouldn't it be equally visible in the first code according to the ADL of `a`?

Comment: ADL only takes place if the initial unqualified lookup doesn't find anything.

Comment: SFINAE is a name of a specific design pattern. It has to be explicitly applied in code. `std::sort` uses it to disambiguate `ExecutionPolicy` overloads for example, but nothing else. This being said, I don't know why it's ambiguous, looks like an issue of having an object and function with the same name in the same namespace: https://godbolt.org/z/G1cMe1Yaz

Comment: Yet another reason not to do `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `std::ranges::sort` is implemented as function object and not a function. From [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) rules:

> For function and function template names, name lookup can associate multiple declarations with the same name, and may obtain additional declarations from argument-dependent lookup. [...]
>
> For all other names (variables, namespaces, classes, etc), name lookup must produce a single declaration in order for the program to compile.

`std::ranges::sort` is a variable, and thus name lookup fails (because there is more than one declaration matching name `sort`). And `std::ranges` algorithms are explicitly allowed to be implemented as function objects (quote from [`std::ranges::sort` cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort)):

> The function-like entities described on this page are *niebloids*, that is: [...]
>
> In practice, they may be implemented as function objects, or with special compiler extensions.

So, as long as standard library implements `std::ranges::sort` as function object (and both libstdc++ and libc++ seem to do that), there is no way to make `sort` name lookup work if you introduce both `std::ranges` and `std` in global namespace.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `std::ranges::sort` is not actually a function template. It is some callable entity with special name lookup properties, sometimes called a [niebloid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62928396/what-is-a-niebloid). As a consequence it doesn't behave like a function (template) in name lookup.

You imported both `std::ranges::sort` and `std::sort` to be found by usual unqualified name lookup. `std::sort` is a function (template), but `std::ranges::sort` isn't.

If unqualified name lookup finds multiple entities and not all of them are functions or function templates, then the name lookup is ambiguous and the program usually ill-formed.

That is what is happening here.