# What is the reason all the ranges algorithms in C++ are wrapped in struct?

Tags: c++, stl, std-ranges

What exactly is the reason that in STL at least all ranges-related algorithms are wrapped in structures, like possible implementation in [std::ranges::upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/upper_bound):

```
struct upper_bound_fn
{
    template</*…*/>
    constexpr I operator()(/*...*) const
    { /* */ }
};

inline constexpr upper_bound_fn upper_bound;
```

(When I try to implement function template without structure, I am getting type-related errors, but most likely this is not related and I just need to write it more careful.)

I don’t see any internal states to keep in structure (like internal information between the calls), so this is not the case. Although, other algorithms could have, so this could be done for consistency.

Another option is to simplify passing these algorithms as function object to other STL algorithms.

Anyway, I am sure that these are not the only cases and there is much more straightforward reasoning for this choice. Can you please help to find it?

Comment: I can't say if this is the reason but functors, objects that act like functions, generally inline better which gives more performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62928396/what-is-a-niebloid

Comment: That's a very specific implementation detail you're asking about. It's not written anywhere in the C++ standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, it's written that they are niebloids, and afaik that's the only way to implement niebloid without extra compiler support?

Comment: Side note: the `stl` tag refers to the Standard Template Library, a hugely influential library from the 1990s that formed the ideological basis for, and no small amount of the implementations of, the C++ Standard Library when C++ standardized in 1998. Avoid using it in questions about the libraries that it influenced unless comparing them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I see. Are we asking here about only something documented in C++ standard? Just want to better understand your point in comment. Is it just a statement or you say that something is wrong in my question?

Comment: @user4581301, this is a question on STL implementation in order to better understand how to write my own algorithms in STL-compatible way. So, with this, this is a question "How to follow STL architecture style". Why in this case `stl` tag is wrong?

Comment: @chrysante, thank you. This could be a possible duplicate by its content, but it is actually hard to find this question for a person who sees the code and not so often uses the word "niebloid". I agree that this is mentioned and even well-covered on the aforementioned page for `std::ranges::upper_bound`, but anyway, for other readers it could be hard to find a linkage between these questions on SO, so my question still could be legitimate one and helping people who are interested in topic.

Comment: In this case, I removed the tag because you're asking about something added to the C++ Standard Library that was not in the Standard Template Library. Since you're interested in the ideology over the implementation, you have a good case for the tag. I will not contest if you want to add the tag back again.

Comment: It seems @user4581301's point was missed because the tag is back.  Damir, STL never contained `ranges`. Read the description of the STL tag: 

_When C++ was standardised, large parts of the STL were adopted into the Standard Library, and these parts in the Standard Library are also sometimes erroneously referred to collectively as "the STL"._

Comment: @Ted Damir was more interested in the ideological underpinnings of the choices made here, and those do reach back to the STL. It's a coin-toss to me over whether it's a misuse of the tag.

Comment: @user4581301 I see. Oh well, the question has a good dupe so I linked to that.

Comment: @Ted That is a good duplicate. Explains the rationale and more. Good reading in general.

Comment: @DamirTenishev • only about a third of STL was standardized into C++98.  I don't think the HP STL from Stepanov & Lee has been maintained for C++11 and later.  Plauger's Dinkum STL might still be maintained.  Microsoft STL is a licensed derivative of Dinkum STL.  EASTL from Pedriana at Electronic Arts may still be maintained.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, my question not about the past ("never contained"), but about present. I could be wrong and latest versions of standard could treat it differently (since standard is always behind fast growing reality), but [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library) for standard library says: "*The containers, iterators, ranges(since C++20), and algorithms libraries provide a C++ program with access to a subset of the most widely used algorithms and data structures.*". So, now it is a question of terms and sources. Please, correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: @Eljay, sorry, you lost me. I was sure STL stands for [C++ Standard Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library) and reflects its current state, not STL history and legacy. Am I wrong?

Comment: No. STL Stands for [**S**tandard **T**emplate **L**ibrary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library). A different library to which the backing ideology of the initial and modern C++ Standard Library owes a lot.

Comment: @user4581301, ops. Thank you. I messed things. *TedLyngmo*, *Eljay*, I take my comments back, sorry for mess and thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: No worries. As you can see, the STL left fingerprints all over the C++ Standard Library, particularly in the containers and algorithms portions. The [`stl` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info) warns about this and offers suggestions of potentially better tags, usually `stdlib` (which has its own ambiguity. Lot of Standard Libraries out there; pretty much every language in mainstream use has one).

Comment: @DamirTenishev • I'm 100% sure STL does **not** stand for C++ Standard Library.  STL predates the C++ Standard Library by many years, and the original implementation of STL was in Ada.

Comment: @DamirTenishev  STL had a single author, Alexander Stepanov,  I rememebr 1993 publications (including his own) in 90s. He presented it to ISO\IEC commitee, led at that time by Andrew Koenig (the very one after whome we call ADL rules "Koenig rule"). By the time the standard language had emerged, its rules had been changed and expanded which required to re-design the library, but many ideas and names were inherited from STL design.  Because hahavior and desing was different from the original,it no longer was an STL, it became known as C++ Standard Library.

Comment: @user4581301, with a second thought I realized why did I mess STL and ranges. Subconsciously, ranges for me where just a next step of development of STL and I realized why; both use the same containers, most of algorithms are the same, the ranges themselves implemented based on STL iterators (at least from first sight) and ranges looks like a logical development of STL and I see that I am not alone here in this mistake: [Ranges: the STL to the Next Level](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/01/12/ranges-stl-to-the-next-level/): "Ranges are the future of the STL.", wording can be dangerous...

Comment: @Eljay, sorry for the mess, I as stated above in the answer to *user4581301*, I messed things; sorry, I take this back. Above the reasons of the mistake in the answer to *user4581301* today.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, thank you, I knew this, but somehow forgot during these long years, I started with STL somewhere in 1994, I guess. I just decided somehow that STL covers entire C++ Standard Library, which is wrong, of course. You are right with the "main ideas and names", my mistakes comes from the fact that mostly I work with CRT, STL and OS API, so I attribute everything to these categories. In a nutshell, I was considering STL growing library and I can't get a clue why ranges wasn't part of STL taking into account that ranges implemented with templates.

Comment: Live and learn.  I learned the same lesson myself, when my mistake (same mistake you made: calling Standard C++ Library "STL") was corrected by my co-worker Alexander Stepanov.

Comment: @Eljay Who? Never heard of him.

Comment: @Eljay Oh? I heard of him from my tutor, Pachikov and his co-worker Dmitry (forgot surname, sadly)

Comment: @DamirTenishev *where just a next step of development of STL* this is why I didn't fight you over the tag. This is a why question, and I figured that ultimately a huge part of the why goes back to the original inspiration.